# Threads and enumeration optimisation

Tags: java, jvm, enumeration

I've got a method in an enumeration that is called by many threads running at same time.

Because the JVM allows only one instance of an enumeration to be allocated in memory, I guess there are some optimisation being done somewhere either by the compiler or the JVM itself in order to avoid the threads having the wait the CPU to access the same position in memory that the methods is, over and over again in order to execute the method for each thread, creating a bottleneck.

When I vary the number of threads from 5 to 300 (I'm executing them through a ScheduledExecutorService) I see no difference in the overall throughput of the system.

Is there really an optimisation done or things are different from what I imagine?

Comment: "The JVM allows only one instance of an enumeration to be allocated in memory". Where did you get that idea?

Comment: Item 3 of 'Effective Java' by Joshua Bloch. (I've got the second edition)

Answer (score 2):

There is no conflict if all the methods are doing is accessing (i.e., reading) the memory.  If you don't change values, and you aren't holding values in instance or static variables, then your methods are "thread-safe" without synchronization.

Either you haven't stated your problem completely, or there isn't one.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I'm actually concerned with how the CPUs access that particular spot of memory that the enumeration's method is allocated at, and not how the enumeration's method access memory, anyway all the objects that the enumeration's method deals with are thread-safe.

Comment: CPUs access memory by loading a memory address onto an address bus and waiting for the value(s) to appear wherever they appear on that particular CPU.  Threading used to involve interrupting the (one) CPU, saving a context, and having some other part of the program execute for a while.  It's a little more complicated than that for multi-CPU machines.  But you haven't said anything about this memory except "access"; there is no synchronization needed just to read memory, and that's normally what causes slowness in multi-threaded apps that have problems.  So I still don't know a better answer.

Comment: There's no problem with lots of threads accessing or reading a single enum value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you might not be seeing any improvement in throughput is because any savings created by executing the tasks in parallel might be obviated by the expense of creating all those threads, without any code or any idea what your program is doing thats hard to say.  Just keep in mind that thread creation and destruction is not free, even with techniques like thread pools, so just creating lots of threads is not guaranteed to increase throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the memory access is read only i.e. no thread is updating the value of the variable, the throughput remains the same. If you  still believe the concurrency issues, try JNI.